# C++ typecast double

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Is there a way in **C++** to **typecast** a *double* into *float*, *int32*, *uint8* or *bool* **without** loosing information? And if it is not possible to return an error?

**Edit:**
Actually I was not clear enough...

I have a function which gets as parameters a **double** and a **type**.
This function should check whether I can typecast the **double** into the **type** without loosing information.

```
bool check_type(double value, enumType type)
{
    switch(type) {
        case enum_uint8:
            return "check wheter value can be typecasted to type"
            break;
        case enum_float:
             .
             .
             .
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: A similar question: Can you represent the state of two bits with just one bit without losing information?

Comment: You can always cast, cast back, and compare.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But that's just reinterpret/type pun. The value as `float`/`int32` etc will then have to be considered meaningless or implementation dependent

Comment: Some error checking is implemented in Boost. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
#include <limits>

template<typename T>
inline bool is_in_allowed_range(double value)
{
    return (
        (value >= static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<T>::min())) &&
        (value <= static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()))
    );
}

bool check_type(double value, enumType type)
{
    switch(type) {
        case enum_uint8:
            return is_in_allowed_range<uint8>(value);
        case enum_float:
            return is_in_allowed_range<float>(value);
        ...
    }
    return false;
}

...

double value = ...;
if (check_type(value, enum_uint8))
{
    uint u = static_cast<uint8>(value);
    // use u as needed ...
}
```

Or simpler:

```
#include <limits>

template<typename T>
bool convert_to_type(double value, T *arg)
{
    if ((value >= static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<T>::min())) &&
        (value <= static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max())))
    {
        *arg = static_cast<T>(value);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

...

double value = ...;
uint8 u;
if (convert_to_type(value, &u))
{
    // use u as needed...
}
```

Comment: Converting a double to a float will in general lose information (precision), even if the value falls inside the range of float values. Range checking is not sufficient to guarantee lossless conversion.

Comment: @IInspectable: true, but pretty much anything you do with floating-point numbers is fairly lossy in general anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No. That would be like burning your dog so you can fit it in an urn for a more convenient house move, then acting surprised when you find out you can't unburn it back to life again.

You will generally get a compiler *warning* if a conversion risks losing data (this is called a "narrowing conversion"), but since this depends on the initial values, which are generally known only at runtime, you cannot get a compiler *error* for it… and C++'s "lightweight" paradigm prevents the language designers from having your program throw an exception or whatever at runtime.

Comment: @erip: Poor thing :(

Answer (score 1):

As `double` uses more bits to store data than `float`, if you store a `double` in a `float` there is a chance that the data will not fit within the size of `float`. Therefore you'll loose some data.

As `int32`, `uint8` stores only integer value, doubles in C++ are stored as (1-bit sign)+2^(11-bit exponent)*1*(52 bit significant), totaling 64 bits. So there is high chance you're loosing data. [this is taken from comment]

But casting is possible.

By the way, you can generate an error by checking the value in double whether it is bigger than the maximum limit of the data type you're going to cast.

Comment: storing a double in an int type is not accurate. doubles in C++ are stored as (1-bit sign)+2^(11-bit exponent)*1*(52 bit significant), totaling 64 bits. this means its not safe to cast as you arent storing a literal number, but a calculated field

Comment: @ByrenHiggin: C++ conversions are not bit-wise copy/truncate operations. They know how to convert IEEE floating-point to two's complement (indeed, this is the very purpose of having the type system in the first place). And _literals_ are entirely orthogonal to this.

Comment: Yes, @ByrenHiggin you're right. I added this to my answer.

Comment: @MASh: Byren is not right. There is nothing "unsafe" about a `double`-to-integer conversion, unless we're counting the possibility of the double storing a signalling NaN representation of course!

Comment: How? Can you explain? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @MASh: There's nothing to explain beyond what I've already stated. Byren needs to explain his point of view. Or perhaps you can explain it to me since you've already adopted it into your answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe there has been some poor language use by me which has led to some confusion on both parts. correct me if i'm even more wrong but IEEE doubles store values un calculated (the binary data is a literal representation of its value) up to 2^53. but higher than that they are stored as calculated fields correct? i was attempting to say that trying to fit 2^53 or larger in a 2^32 int32 field will lose value, and thus is not a "safe" (in the context of retaining value) conversion for data integrity. Does this clear up my point of view?

Comment: @ByrenHiggin: Sorry not really sure what you're saying. Perhaps we're talking at cross-purposes; I don't know. If all you're saying is that double->int32 is a narrowing conversion then, yes, we know this: every answer already says so. But it's not "unsafe". It sounds to me like you're confusing a typical conversion with a "reinterpret_cast" which would not take the IEEE encoding into account and instead pretend it were in 2's complement. For one, you appear to call 2's complement "a literal representation of its value", when there is in fact no such thing: _all_ values are encoded in some way.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to typecast a double to a float, but you will experience rounding of your number, so it will not be accurate to the previous number. doubles cannot safely be put into integer-similar types or booleans.

if you are doing checks at run-time you are unable to get variable types in base C++, but if you are doing them at compile time you can use variable::typeid to check. the option to check for loss of information is to cast one way to the desired type, cast back to the previous type, and then compare the results to see if information has been lost